# How to troubleshoot network from customers perspective?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, network-monitoring, troubleshooting, monitoring

We have a web application that we host that is customized for multiple customers.  Each customer accesses their version of the site via their own custom subdomain.  We are running into an issue where ONE customer makes a claim that there is an issue with their site -- site unavailable, certain functions timing out, or generically just 'slow'.

Our support representatives get a report/email/call from the customer when this happens -- and try to reproduce the issues.  More times than not, they cannot.  If the issue still persists, they end up engaging our IT group, and setting up a troubleshooting call with the customer's IT group.

The customers are usually on their own corporate networks, although their sites can be accessed via internet as well.  Once our support rep CANNOT reproduce the issue AND no other customers are reporting issues, we assume the issues are not systemic and have a high probability of being within the customer's network.

Since we cannot ping/traceroute to/from the clients making the request and see all hops, it turns into pointing the finger at each other with seemingly no way to **PROVE** where the issue is.

1. What can we do to provide EVIDENCE that our service and network are not the issue?
2. What is the best way to show that from our webserver to our ISP (in both directions) is OK?
3. Are there any recommended tools we can put in place to monitor #2?

Comment: Will they let you put a machine on their network which can monitor ping/traceroute or that you can ssh/rdp into to see how well it works from their network?

Comment: Negative.  To them, we are just another site (like Google, Bing) so they typically see an issue with our site, then test those sites to 'make sure' its not their internet connection that is down, then they pull the fire alarm.

Comment: Ping and Traceroute aren't the greatest tools for this kind of issue. Neither one can you give you any in depth insight into the problem. They can tell you if the link is completely unavailable but that would be fairly obvious without using either one. Ping showing latency won't show you where the latency is originating and due to the nature of how Tracert works I wouldn't rely on that to give me any useful information about the path unless there were glaring problems in the path. You need to be able to test the path from them to you using "real" traffic, such as using iperf or QCheck.

Comment: I would use nslookup, ping and tracert to establish the type of problem you're dealing with. Nslookup to verify that DNS name resolution is working, tracert to verify that a route exists from them to you and ping to look for latency. From that point on you'll need better, more specific tools to find the cause.

Comment: Setup a host on a VPS somewhere on systems completely different from your production network.  Design a system that will use javascript to run a series of tests, and report the data to the user.  Have your users visit this host that will run the tests when you have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are many a service (some, even free) that will "monitor" your site from various parts of the world, report metrics and response times and the like.  Personally, I would utilize one or two of these so I could point the customer at them.  (The ones that come to my mind immediately are [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/), [uptrends](http://www.uptrends.com/aspx/free-html-site-page-load-check-tool.aspx) and [loadimpact](http://loadimpact.com/page-analyzer), but this is not my specialty, so I'm sure there are better, more specific services out there that would fit your use-case better.)

In any event, the point of these tools and services is to get you to a point where you can credibly say "Look, it's working and pretty zippy for the rest of the world, none of our other customers have issues, and these worldwide results look to pretty firmly suggest it's an issue specific to your setup."

No, it's not evidence, but if they're not going to let you host a box on their network to monitor with, it's about as good as you'll probably do.  You could also try talking reason to them (though that sounds like a waste of time) - how much data is involved in a Google search, versus a hosted service like you provide - of course Google and Bing are going to seem fast... they seem fast on a 56k modem.  Doesn't mean anything about the state of the network utilization because so little data is used.

At the end of the day, bear in mind that not all customers are worth having.  If they're costing you more money in support troubleshooting their network bullshit than they generate as customers, it's time to tell them to take their business elsewhere.

Comment: I like the approach suggested, but I disagree with the third and fourth paragraphs in general.  1) It is evidence (perhaps not proof that the issue is a customer issue, but strong evidence that it isn't (or is) your issue)  2) It seems like this is a frequent enough problem to ask for a general solution, so the issue may not be with the customers.

Comment: @Slartibartfast  The issue sounds to be with the customer's attitude/ignorance.  "Google works, so it must be your site" is just so stupid (especially when repeated multiple times) that it seems to me that the customers are unable or unwilling to understand even the basics on which this all lies (and on which any troubleshooting depends).

Answer (score -2):

I recommend asking the customer to install TeamViewer and politely request them to share the TeamViewer key, so that you can view what's going on, and (under customer's supervision) check all relevant settings from 'their' point of view.

Also remind them to uninstall TeamViewer or generate new TeamViewer keys for their security.

***Edited to add:*** I've seen this happen firsthand in my own network. But this is happening with my network as the 'customer' side; apparently, there was a mistake with proxy.pac causing parts of the website being accessed to be using "DIRECT" instead of the corporate proxy, so that part of the website always fail.

Comment: So, your suggestion to troubleshoot what seems like a slow link or network utilization issue... is to use remote screen sharing software over the affected link?  That's not a good plan.  It doesn't sound like the customer's going to be very open to that anyway, which is a good thing, because this idea has "blowback" and "fail" written all over it, in my opinion.  (I can already practically hear the customer saying "See, it's slow!!  That proves it's your fault!!")

Comment: ...and purchase a commercial use license of course, right?

Comment: It doesn't mean either end of the link is slow. I've been in @tresstylez' position before, diagnosing our web service/app/site due to a customer complaint. Sometimes it's a routing failure at a peering point. Sometimes it's a Packetshaper at the customer that no one knew about, blocking certain Websphere components. Sometimes it's a problem with our website. And when I did this, I was not at the location where our servers were hosted, so I wasn't on the same link.

Comment: @HopelessN00b who says it was a customer's slow link? No such claim on the question proper. Question only declares that the **affected website** is slow. Nowhere is it declared that the **customer's link** is slow. Since questioner already declared that it is not possible to put a machines on customer's side, what other alternatives do you have?

Comment: @EEAA yes, but **only for the side giving support**; TeamViewer's FAQ clearly indicates that clients (that is, the side being supported) needs no license. Consider this an investment, because one license can be used to connect to different clients, as long as only one client is being connected to.

Comment: PS I wonder why my answer is being downvoted...

Comment: The answer is being down-voted (IMHO) because you don't address the poster's concerns.  They weren't asking for a way to go through the existing process differently; they are trying to avoid it and prove that the issue is on the customer side much earlier in the conversation.